# How to make the variable not start new line

Tags: javascript

I am making a website where you have to input a link, and it makes javascript, but after imputing the variable, it adds a line so it doesn't work.

This is the code I am using

```
    var url = prompt("Enter the link you want the app to go to.");
    document.getElementById(2).onclick = "window.open('" + url + "', '_blank');'>";
```

Anyone got suggestions?

Comment: It looks like you might have a stray `>` in your window.open call, that could be messing things up. Not sure what you mean by "adds a line", can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is something like that

```
var url = prompt("Enter the link you want the app to go to.");
if(url){
    document.getElementById("xxxx").onclick=function(){
    window.open(url, '_blank');
  }
}
```

Comment: I need the string to go into a HTML onclick attribute

Answer (score 0):

You just dont need to use these strings to set url variable in window.open method.

You could try this:

```
 var url = prompt("Enter the link you want the app to go to.");

 document.getElementById(2).onclick = () => window.open(url, '_blank');
```

Answer (score 0):

Quickest fix: First remove that stray `<`, as @audiodude said. Then use the function constructor.

```
var url = prompt("Enter the link you want the app to go to.");

document.getElementById(2).onclick = new Function("window.open('" + url + "', '_blank');")
```